# PDF page becomes blank on print

Tags: pdf, adobe, postscript, reader, printer-control-language

I have a strange issue with a PDF file. Printing from Adobe Reader works fine on A4 but on A3 the second page is blank.
The PDF is almost 200mb containing HQ vector+graphics

Windows 7 x64
Printer: Konica Minolta bizhub c452
Driver: PCL6 driver from konicaminolta

- If I use the PS driver it works but it generates huge file and it takes forever to send it to the printer.
- From another PC with Acrobat Pro and the same PCL6 driver it works fine

***Tried:***
Using Adobe reader DC (same results)
Using print as .xps (same, generates file with a second page empty)

I wonder it there's no limit somewhere on filesize when spooling to the printer with the PCL driver. It's interesting that it happens also when printing to .xps, so the problem happens somewhere during flattening

Comment: Seems more like a Windows problem than anything to do with PostScript, especially since the PostScript output works.... Note that Acrobat generates its own PostScript, it does not use the system printer driver, so that might be one reason why it works. For PCL it must use the system driver, which likely results in a huge bitmap being wrapped up in PCL commands. Possibly your system simply runs out of memory or scratch disk space.

Comment: Just Installed PDF XChange Viewer and it prints OK. Also found some portable Acrobat Pro XI and it worked too.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe is having another issue (Oct. 2018) with images not printing, which can be parts of a PDF or the entire PDF not printing. The fix is in the print dialog box, click on Advanced and select "Print as Image" and it should print fine. In Reader you can't select dpi, but you can in the full Acrobat. Try it, worked fine for our business PDFs.

Comment: I am aware that print as image usually works but if the colors and quality matter (design purpose) then this is not a solution.